# angular strap - bs-tabs not refreshing properly when ng-repeat points to new array object

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to build a tab set that would dynamically change on user action using bs-tabs angularstrap directive and ng-repeat (Say initially the tabs were a,b,c. On some user action it should change to x,y,z)

I am trying to do this by pointing the ng-repeat to a new array object on an user action say a click of a button.
Instead of the tab set getting refreshed, I am noticing a strange behavior

Ive recreated it in this plnkr, please have a look at it,

http://plnkr.co/edit/bpKDx56bieIshKaedzv6?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularStrap - Tab directive</title>

    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//mgcrea.github.com/angular-strap/css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- required libraries -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//mgcrea.github.com/angular-strap/js/angular-strap.js"></script>

    <!-- optional libraries -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.0.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fastclick/0.6.0/fastclick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r224/prettify.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
          <div data-fade="1" ng-model="tabs.activeTab" bs-tabs>
            <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" data-title="{{tab.title}}"><p>{{tab.content}}</p></div>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeTabs()">Show different set of tabs</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/directives/tab.js) it seems that the tab directive observes the active tab value and refreshes only the tab content using transclusion, whereas the tab title is only assigned initially.
I think the only way to change title dinamically is creating a new directive that creates a tab directive dinamically, initializing it with the fresh values.